# Image is not being displayed once added runat="server"

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, runatserver

I have and `<img/>` tag in my asp.net project. I want to add `runat="server"` to it.

However once I add it the image is not being displayed anymore and rather I get a string like this display in the browser:

```
 " id="GridView1_smallImage1_1" style="max-width: 95%; max-height: 95%; margin:0 auto;" alt="image" />
```

He is the image itself:

```
<img id="smallImage1" style="max-width: 95%; max-height: 95%; margin:0 auto;" src='data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("Image2") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image2")) : string.Empty%>' alt="image"/>
```

Could someone explain why this is happening and what would be the approach of changing the src in the code behind?

Comment: try using a native asp image control? <asp:image id="smallImage1" runat="server" />

Comment: yeah but my src wont work for ImageURL and I would have to do conversions in the code behind instead of having just one line of code in my aspx page....

Comment: <asp:Image id="smallImage1" runat=server" ImageUrl =<%# string.Format("~/image/{0}",Eval("path"))%>

Comment: @David what is that piece of code?

Comment: <asp:Image id="smallImage1" runat=server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("~/imageLocation/{0}", Eval("Image2") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image2")) : string.Empty%>' alt="image"/>

Comment: ok cool Ill try it out

Comment: but there is no image location i just get it from my sql datasource parameter

Comment: Show that markup that gives you trouble. You may just have a quote out of place.

Comment: @Crowcoder `<asp:Image id="smallImage1" runat="server" ImageUrl='data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("Image2") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image2")) : string.Empty%>' />`

Comment: nothing... just empty in chrome and no image image in IE

Comment: you will have to set the source in the BE if you want to do it like data:image. so smallImage1.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(....);

Comment: c# again just stooping me from doing things nicely

Comment: @whiterabbitj that isn't an <img> tag, what is the exact markup that caused you to ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a native asp image control and then either

Set with predefined image location:

```
<asp:Image id="smallImage1" runat=server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("~/imageLocation/{0}", Eval("Image2") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image2")) : string.Empty%>' alt="image"/>
```

or set the source in the code behind if extracting from external source:

```
smallImage1.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(....);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is this : '~/imageLocation/{0}.' As i Dont have the location should i just delete it?

Comment: Nah sorry doesn't answer the question will have to down vote... jk

Comment: you need to do option 2.

Comment: ill use javascript instead for the problem